# How to add controls into xuggler video

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, xuggler, xuggle

Alright,I used an example code for xuggler which creates a java swing frame which reproduces video and audio from a certain file.I also embedded the code into another application though.Had to make a thread out of it in order to avoid the heap out of memory error.

It was this code:
http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/DecodeAndPlayAudioAndVideo.java

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright (c) 2008, 2010 Xuggle Inc.  All rights reserved.
 *  
 * This file is part of Xuggle-Xuggler-Main.
 *
 * Xuggle-Xuggler-Main is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * Xuggle-Xuggler-Main is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
 * along with Xuggle-Xuggler-Main.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 *******************************************************************************/

package com.xuggle.xuggler.demos;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

import com.xuggle.xuggler.Global;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IPixelFormat;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStream;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStreamCoder;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoResampler;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.Utils;

/**
 * Takes a media container, finds the first video stream,
 * decodes that stream, and then plays the audio and video.
 *
 * This code does a VERY coarse job of matching time-stamps, and thus
 * the audio and video will float in and out of slight sync.  Getting
 * time-stamps syncing-up with audio is very system dependent and left
 * as an exercise for the reader.
 * 
 * @author aclarke
 *
 */
public class DecodeAndPlayAudioAndVideo
{

  /**
   * The audio line we'll output sound to; it'll be the default audio device on your system if available
   */
  private static SourceDataLine mLine;

  /**
   * The window we'll draw the video on.
   * 
   */
  private static VideoImage mScreen = null;

  private static long mSystemVideoClockStartTime;

  private static long mFirstVideoTimestampInStream;

  /**
   * Takes a media container (file) as the first argument, opens it,
   * plays audio as quickly as it can, and opens up a Swing window and displays
   * video frames with <i>roughly</i> the right timing.
   *  
   * @param args Must contain one string which represents a filename
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    if (args.length <= 0)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("must pass in a filename as the first argument");

    String filename = args[0];

    // Let's make sure that we can actually convert video pixel formats.
    if (!IVideoResampler.isSupported(IVideoResampler.Feature.FEATURE_COLORSPACECONVERSION))
      throw new RuntimeException("you must install the GPL version of Xuggler (with IVideoResampler support) for this demo to work");

    // Create a Xuggler container object
    IContainer container = IContainer.make();

    // Open up the container
    if (container.open(filename, IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not open file: " + filename);

    // query how many streams the call to open found
    int numStreams = container.getNumStreams();

    // and iterate through the streams to find the first audio stream
    int videoStreamId = -1;
    IStreamCoder videoCoder = null;
    int audioStreamId = -1;
    IStreamCoder audioCoder = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < numStreams; i++)
    {
      // Find the stream object
      IStream stream = container.getStream(i);
      // Get the pre-configured decoder that can decode this stream;
      IStreamCoder coder = stream.getStreamCoder();

      if (videoStreamId == -1 && coder.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO)
      {
        videoStreamId = i;
        videoCoder = coder;
      }
      else if (audioStreamId == -1 && coder.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO)
      {
        audioStreamId = i;
        audioCoder = coder;
      }
    }
    if (videoStreamId == -1 && audioStreamId == -1)
      throw new RuntimeException("could not find audio or video stream in container: "+filename);

    /*
     * Check if we have a video stream in this file.  If so let's open up our decoder so it can
     * do work.
     */
    IVideoResampler resampler = null;
    if (videoCoder != null)
    {
      if(videoCoder.open() < 0)
        throw new RuntimeException("could not open audio decoder for container: "+filename);

      if (videoCoder.getPixelType() != IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24)
      {
        // if this stream is not in BGR24, we're going to need to
        // convert it.  The VideoResampler does that for us.
        resampler = IVideoResampler.make(videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight(), IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24,
            videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight(), videoCoder.getPixelType());
        if (resampler == null)
          throw new RuntimeException("could not create color space resampler for: " + filename);
      }
      /*
       * And once we have that, we draw a window on screen
       */
      openJavaVideo();
    }

    if (audioCoder != null)
    {
      if (audioCoder.open() < 0)
        throw new RuntimeException("could not open audio decoder for container: "+filename);

      /*
       * And once we have that, we ask the Java Sound System to get itself ready.
       */
      try
      {
        openJavaSound(audioCoder);
      }
      catch (LineUnavailableException ex)
      {
        throw new RuntimeException("unable to open sound device on your system when playing back container: "+filename);
      }
    }


    /*
     * Now, we start walking through the container looking at each packet.
     */
    IPacket packet = IPacket.make();
    mFirstVideoTimestampInStream = Global.NO_PTS;
    mSystemVideoClockStartTime = 0;
    while(container.readNextPacket(packet) >= 0)
    {
      /*
       * Now we have a packet, let's see if it belongs to our video stream
       */
      if (pac
    enter code here

ket.getStreamIndex() == videoStreamId)
      {
        /*
         * We allocate a new picture to get the data out of Xuggler
         */
        IVideoPicture picture = IVideoPicture.make(videoCoder.getPixelType(),
            videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight());

        /*
         * Now, we decode the video, checking for any errors.
         * 
         */
        int bytesDecoded = videoCoder.decodeVideo(picture, packet, 0);
        if (bytesDecoded < 0)
          throw new RuntimeException("got error decoding audio in: " + filename);

        /*
         * Some decoders will consume data in a packet, but will not be able to construct
         * a full video picture yet.  Therefore you should always check if you
         * got a complete picture from the decoder
         */
        if (picture.isComplete())
        {
          IVideoPicture newPic = picture;
          /*
           * If the resampler is not null, that means we didn't get the video in BGR24 format and
           * need to convert it into BGR24 format.
           */
          if (resampler != null)
          {
            // we must resample
            newPic = IVideoPicture.make(resampler.getOutputPixelFormat(), picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight());
            if (resampler.resample(newPic, picture) < 0)
              throw new RuntimeException("could not resample video from: " + filename);
          }
          if (newPic.getPixelType() != IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24)
            throw new RuntimeException("could not decode video as BGR 24 bit data in: " + filename);

          long delay = millisecondsUntilTimeToDisplay(newPic);
          // if there is no audio stream; go ahead and hold up the main thread.  We'll end
          // up caching fewer video pictures in memory that way.
          try
          {
            if (delay > 0)
              Thread.sleep(delay);
          }
          catch (InterruptedException e)
          {
            return;
          }

          // And finally, convert the picture to an image and display it

          mScreen.setImage(Utils.videoPictureToImage(newPic));
        }
      }
      else if (packet.getStreamIndex() == audioStreamId)
      {
        /*
         * We allocate a set of samples with the same number of channels as the
         * coder tells us is in this buffer.
         * 
         * We also pass in a buffer size (1024 in our example), although Xuggler
         * will probably allocate more space than just the 1024 (it's not important why).
         */
        IAudioSamples samples = IAudioSamples.make(1024, audioCoder.getChannels());

        /*
         * A packet can actually contain multiple sets of samples (or frames of samples
         * in audio-decoding speak).  So, we may need to call decode audio multiple
         * times at different offsets in the packet's data.  We capture that here.
         */
        int offset = 0;

        /*
         * Keep going until we've processed all data
         */
        while(offset < packet.getSize())
        {
          int bytesDecoded = audioCoder.decodeAudio(samples, packet, offset);
          if (bytesDecoded < 0)
            throw new RuntimeException("got error decoding audio in: " + filename);
          offset += bytesDecoded;
          /*
           * Some decoder will consume data in a packet, but will not be able to construct
           * a full set of samples yet.  Therefore you should always check if you
           * got a complete set of samples from the decoder
           */
          if (samples.isComplete())
          {
            // note: this call will block if Java's sound buffers fill up, and we're
            // okay with that.  That's why we have the video "sleeping" occur
            // on another thread.
            playJavaSound(samples);
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        /*
         * This packet isn't part of our video stream, so we just silently drop it.
         */
        do {} while(false);
      }

    }
    /*
     * Technically since we're exiting anyway, these will be cleaned up by 
     * the garbage collector... but because we're nice people and want
     * to be invited places for Christmas, we're going to show how to clean up.
     */
    if (videoCoder != null)
    {
      videoCoder.close();
      videoCoder = null;
    }
    if (audioCoder != null)
    {
      audioCoder.close();
      audioCoder = null;
    }
    if (container !=null)
    {
      container.close();
      container = null;
    }
    closeJavaSound();
    closeJavaVideo();
  }

  private static long millisecondsUntilTimeToDisplay(IVideoPicture picture)
  {
    /**
     * We could just display the images as quickly as we decode them, but it turns
     * out we can decode a lot faster than you think.
     * 
     * So instead, the following code does a poor-man's version of trying to
     * match up the frame-rate requested for each IVideoPicture with the system
     * clock time on your computer.
     * 
     * Remember that all Xuggler IAudioSamples and IVideoPicture objects always
     * give timestamps in Microseconds, relative to the first decoded item.  If
     * instead you used the packet timestamps, they can be in different units depending
     * on your IContainer, and IStream and things can get hairy quickly.
     */
    long millisecondsToSleep = 0;
    if (mFirstVideoTimestampInStream == Global.NO_PTS)
    {
      // This is our first time through
      mFirstVideoTimestampInStream = picture.getTimeStamp();
      // get the starting clock time so we can hold up frames
      // until the right time.
      mSystemVideoClockStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      millisecondsToSleep = 0;
    } else {
      long systemClockCurrentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      long millisecondsClockTimeSinceStartofVideo = systemClockCurrentTime - mSystemVideoClockStartTime;
      // compute how long for this frame since the first frame in the stream.
      // remember that IVideoPicture and IAudioSamples timestamps are always in MICROSECONDS,
      // so we divide by 1000 to get milliseconds.
      long millisecondsStreamTimeSinceStartOfVideo = (picture.getTimeStamp() - mFirstVideoTimestampInStream)/1000;
      final long millisecondsTolerance = 50; // and we give ourselfs 50 ms of tolerance
      millisecondsToSleep = (millisecondsStreamTimeSinceStartOfVideo -
          (millisecondsClockTimeSinceStartofVideo+millisecondsTolerance));
    }
    return millisecondsToSleep;
  }

  /**
   * Opens a Swing window on screen.
   */
  private static void openJavaVideo()
  {
    mScreen = new VideoImage();
  }

  /**
   * Forces the swing thread to terminate; I'm sure there is a right
   * way to do this in swing, but this works too.
   */
  private static void closeJavaVideo()
  {
    System.exit(0);
  }

  private static void openJavaSound(IStreamCoder aAudioCoder) throws LineUnavailableException
  {
    AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(aAudioCoder.getSampleRate(),
        (int)IAudioSamples.findSampleBitDepth(aAudioCoder.getSampleFormat()),
        aAudioCoder.getChannels(),
        true, /* xuggler defaults to signed 16 bit samples */
        false);
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
    mLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    /**
     * if that succeeded, try opening the line.
     */
    mLine.open(audioFormat);
    /**
     * And if that succeed, start the line.
     */
    mLine.start();


  }

  private static void playJavaSound(IAudioSamples aSamples)
  {
    /**
     * We're just going to dump all the samples into the line.
     */
    byte[] rawBytes = aSamples.getData().getByteArray(0, aSamples.getSize());
    mLine.write(rawBytes, 0, aSamples.getSize());
  }

  private static void closeJavaSound()
  {
    if (mLine != null)
    {
      /*
       * Wait for the line to finish playing
       */
      mLine.drain();
      /*
       * Close the line.
       */
      mLine.close();
      mLine=null;
    }
  }
}
```

Now I wanna know,what are the method names for the video to stop,play,or maybe go fullscreen?

Comment: Please post the code within the question. Code hiding under links is frowned upon on StackOverflow.

Comment: done,edited the original post

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not how it works. In this question you may as well receive no help, anyway, but for future reference, SO people expect quite a bit more effort put into the question. Like trimming down the code to the relevant one or two screenfuls.

Comment: Well based on your previous comment I was thinking you did want a whole overview of the code.To be honest I do not think anyone even needs to see the code for my question because my question is pretty precise,but I still wanted to give them a link to the code just in case.

Comment: Actually, your question is by quite a margin overly broad. SO is about specific questions concerning specific coding problems. You are basically asking for a bona fide tutorial on xuggler. You mention in passing "to avoid out of memory problems" as if it is obvious to everyone what you are talking about. Your overall attitude is way too relaxed and conversational to attract people's effort.

Comment: Note that I am saying all this from an entirely uninvolved perspective; I have no idea what xuggler even is. My only motivation is to help you fit in here.

Comment: Maybe you are right,and I was worried it would be too wide.Check my latest edit at the bottom.Sorry I am still not an expert level programmer.I was in programming for like 2 years now...And just lately I have finished my first serious application.

Comment: Do you know of a programming oriented site where my more conversational style would be more appreciated?Otherwise I like SO and I am here to learn,contribute and cooperate.

Comment: Yes, that last sentence gives a much more concrete idea of what you are looking for. Try to avoid any ccolloquialisms like "wanna" and similar, this does not belong to discourse among professionals. As for other sites, usually there will be a Google Group run by the xuggler community. Outside the world of Android I haven't met any communities which are appreciative of informal communication style.